# How to change Corner Radius of NSView in Swift Language

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview, swift

changing corner radius of NSView should be pretty straight forward however i am getting error message "fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None". is there a chance i am doing this with 10.9 not 10.10 and this is happening due framework differences? or the code is wrong.

```
class aRoundView: NSView {

    let cornerRad = 5.0

    init(frame: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.layer.cornerRadius  = cornerRad
    }

    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect)
    {
        super.drawRect(dirtyRect)
        NSColor.redColor().setFill()
        NSRectFill(dirtyRect)
    }
}
```

## EDIT

calling it in

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification?) {

    let aView = mainViewTest(frame: NSMakeRect(0, 0, 100, 100))
    self.window.contentView.addSubview(aView)

}
```

actually it is not just that. any iteration with self.layer gives same result, backgroundcolor etc.

Comment: What call specifically causes the error?

Comment: Can you identify the line that causes the error? I pasted your code into the playground and it gives me no error.

Comment: It would be `self.layer` that is `nil` in that initialization. Is it a layer-backed view? Try `self.wantsLayer = true` before that call.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is because `self.layer` is an optional value, which is currently not set. Add `self.wantsLayer = true` before `self.layer.cornerRadius`, to make sure a proper `layer` exists.

```
init(frame: NSRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.wantsLayer = true
    self.layer.cornerRadius  = cornerRad
}
```